# Can the parent have less columns than child in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to implement outline view in my app using NSOutlineView, but in my app the outer layer (parent) should have only one column (Brand) and inner layer (children) should have 5-6 columns (Size,Type,Image, etc.).

Is it possible to achieve, and how to do so if it is?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have “full-width” cells for “group rows” in a `NSOutlineView` (or `NSTableView`).

If you’re using a cell-based outline view, implement `outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item:`
 in your `NSOutlineViewDelegate`.  Before this method is invoked with any of the existing columns, it will be invoked with a column of `nil`.  For the corresponding rows,  return a prototype `NSCell`, and in your other data source/delegate methods likewise return the corresponding information for a `nil` “column”.  You just need to create a generic `NSTextFieldCell` for this; no need to style it yourself unless you want to.  More information in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3adataCellForTableColumn%3arow%3a) or take a look at some Apple [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PhotoSearch/Introduction/Intro.html).

If you’re using a view-based outline view, implement the equivalent `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:`.  Unfortunately the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOutlineViewDelegate/outlineView%3aviewForTableColumn%3aitem%3a) is currently pretty nonexistent, but the [corresponding `NSTableViewDelegate` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForTableColumn%3arow%3a) is documented, and you can look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample.

The appearance of the full-width item will vary based on the highlight style (`selectionHighlightStyle`) configured for your outline view; from your description, it sounds like you would want “regular” rather than “source list” behavior.